# Android: Issue with getting Optimal Preview Size for Camera on latest Samsung Galaxy devices

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, landscape

For my Android app, I am using the below code to get the optimal preview screen size. This works for most of the devices but I am facing some issues with this code on Samsung Galaxy 7 and 7 Edge specifically. The preview works fine in portrait mode but in the landscape mode, the preview screen is zoomed out and goes out of the screen. Is there anything I am doing wrong here or do I have to handle it differently for the Samsung devices?

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> previewSizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    if (sizes == null)
        return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;

        //Selecting the preview size for which the difference between the ratio and the target ratio is minimum AND
        //The difference between the target height AND preview size height and the target width and the preview size width is minimum
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) < minDiff) {

            minDiff = Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio);
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(size.width - w, 2) + Math.pow(size.height - h, 2));

            if (distance < minDist) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDist = distance;
            }
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}
```